# How to create a Sqlite table with OnConflict constraint on a primary or unique column Using SQLite.swift Library for iOS ?

Tags: ios, sqlite.swift

I am new to iOS with android background. and after quite sometime searching how to persist data for my project I chose to use SQLite.swift Library by stephencelis. Now, I want to do a simple Table creation:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableName ( 
                    id  INTEGER,
                    name TEXT NOT NULL, 
                    CONSTRAINT Key PRIMARY KEY (id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
```

but I can't find in the documentation any swift keyword for "ON CONFLICT" ... So My implementation now is like this:

```
    static func createTable (db:Connection) {
       do {
           try db.run(TableName.create(temporary: false, ifNotExists: true, block: {
           t in 
           t.column(id, primaryKey: true)
           t.column(name)
           }))
       } catch {
           print ("Unable to create Table TableName")
       }
    }
```

How to add the ON CONFLICT clause?